# Is this a valid way of holding a static reference to and Activity/Context? Why shouldn't I do this?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity, memory-leaks

I have an abstract `BaseFragmentActivity` class, which all of my Activities in my android application extend. In this class I maintain a static reference to the currently running activity as `sCurrentActivity`. In my `onStart()` lifecycle callback, I set this like this:

```
public abstract class BaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity { 

    private static BaseFragmentActivity sCurrentActivity;

    public static BaseFragmentActivity getCurrentActivity(){
        return sCurrentActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        sCurrentActivity = this;
    }
```

Using this, from anywhere in the code I can get the current activity/context by calling:

`BaseFragmentActivity.getCurrentActivity()`

So everything I've read says I should not be holding static references to Activities/Contexts. **But if this static variable is shared among all activities, am I actually leaking a Context every time I start a new Activity?**
I've read through Romain Guy's post about avoiding memory leaks (http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html), watched performance pattern videos on the android developer channel about leaking views (https://youtu.be/h7qHsk1nWKI and https://youtu.be/BkbHeFHn8JY) and I'm reasonably confident this is bad practice. But can someone help me understand the exact reason why and where this leaks, if it does. I want to make a case to remove this, but I need a stronger argument than "I think it's leaking a context".

EDIT:
For clarity, this is a codebase which I have inherited, where everything is very tightly coupled and messy, this function is used almost anywhere one would look for a context object. Inside Dialog button callbacks to fire new intents, inside array adapters, even (for reasons unknown) inside fragments to get views inside the parent activity! I need to justify a refactor effort to our product owner over new features in a way they will understand.

Comment: You have already watched videos and read blogs from expert and you still asking the same question   Is it bad to use ref of activity

Answer (score 3):

You are leaking one activity instance at most in a given time. If you add

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        sCurrentActivity = null;
    }
```

Then you will not be leaking any.

But i didnt really get why you need to do this, what are you trying to acheive?

EDIT: after you explain what you are trying to acheive, it seem more rational to me to extend Application, and hold a static reference to it and access it from anywhere, I think it is better for 3 reasons :

1. Application instance is kept alive anyway as far as i know for as long as your app is running, and sometimes even when its not running while the system doesnt bother releasing it so that it will be ready for the next launch of your app.
2. I bet Activity object has much more memory overhead then Application object
3. When your application object is killed, I am 99% sure that your process sieze to exist too, so the static reference will not cause a leak.

Some code example :

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static App context;
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       context = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do this, but once the new activity starts, won't it replace that old reference and allow it to be collected anyway?

Comment: Yes but what about the meantime? between call to onStop to the next onStart there is time that you hold the activity for no real reason apperantly...

Comment: Still, I think it is more important for your learning to explain what you are trying to acheive and we can lead you to better approach

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks. I want to basically remove this code from the codebase, but it since it is everywhere this mandates a much wider refactor. How can I explain to a non-developer (our product owner) that is bad practice and it is worth my time to refactor, re-architect and fix over building new user features.

Comment: That i will leave for you to handle :)